# Need json in array type

Tags: angular, laravel

I need to json array type in laravel. i am getting json in object type.

```
$category = new Categories;
return Response::json(array(
    'error' => false,
    'category' => $category->get_active_category(),
    'status_code' => 200
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$category = new Categories;
$data = array(
    'error' => false,
    'category' => $category->get_active_category(),
    'status_code' => 200
);
return Response::json($data);
```

Comment: Thanks Kenneth we have change in function $category->get_active_category()->toarray() it works for me.